# C# alternative to enums for a n:m-relation

Tags: c#, casting, enums

there are several threads on value-ranges in enums (not possible).
But I have the following problem and search the best solution, where none of the provided once really satisfied me.

A specification of a protocol says that byte[x] of a message, the messagetype, has the following possible values (fantasy values):

```
0x00 = get
0x01 = set 
0x02 to 0xFF = identify
```

So there are only 3 different logical options, which would best be dealt with in an enum. But one of the n logical options has m different numerical counterparts, which is impossible to be dealt with in an enum.

Now what is the best (cleanest) solution for such a problem?
I could build a class

```
class MessageType {
    public enum MessageTypeEnum {
        get = 0x00, 
        set = 0x01, 
        identify = 0x02
    }

    public static MessageTypeEnum getLogicalValue (byte numericalValue)
    {
       if (numericalValue < 0x02) 
          return (MessageTypeEnum(numericalValue)); 
       else
          return MessageTypeEnum.identify;
    }
}
```

I could also create a class without an enum, but with static members.

Either way there is one Problem: If someone tries to dispatch a packet, he might use

```
if (messageBytes[x] == (byte)MessageTypeEnum.identify) {
    // do stuff
}
```

But messageByte[x] could be anything between 0x02 and 0xFF, so "hitting" the value specified in the enum would be pure luck. On the other side I want the enum (or static member) to be public for easy message-building.

Can I somehow enforce the use of my getLogicalValue()-Function?
Is there a more elegant solution?

All I want is an easy and well-structured way to link logical values to numerical values in a n:m relation. Especially as the given protocol has many such cases and I would like to keep my code neat.

Thanks for your help and time :)

Janis

Comment: I suppose you mean `messageBytes[x] == (byte)...` instead of `=`, which would be an assignment. You can never fully prevent folks from casting one type forcefully into another (except if you override the cast operator and throw an exception). If somebody wants to abuse your code, they will.

Comment: Yep, I indeed meant "==". That mistake happens to me allot as I come from other languages and directly typed the code in the comment window. As for the code-abuse: The thing is that I could do that mistake myself when using the .dll I want to build, as Enums (usually) are bidirectional function (logical value <=> numerical value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you to drop the idea of using enums and create a custom type for this.

It could be either struct or class; it doesn't matter. You could solve the equals problem by overloading the `==` operator and providing custom implementation.

Something like this:

```
public class MessageType
{
    private readonly byte value;
    private MessageType(byte value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static readonly MessageType Get = new MessageType(0);
    public static readonly MessageType Set = new MessageType(1);
    public static readonly MessageType Identify = new MessageType(2);


    public static bool operator ==(MessageType m, byte b)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(m, null))
            return false;

        if (m.value == 2 && b >= 2 && b <= 0xff)//I think <= check is redundant
            return true;
        return m.value == b;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(MessageType m, byte b)
    {
        return !(m == b);
    }
   //Need to implement Equals, GetHashCode etc
}
```

Don't forget to implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` for consistency in equals implementation.

Comment: This is is the best answer so far and also close to what I figured out myself. But i was actually looking for a more elegant solution. The thing is that I have some 20 such enums in the protocol, which would be ALLOT of code compared to simple enums. I did not accept this answer as solution yet, as I am still hoping for something better (though I doubt there is). Thanks again though :)

Comment: @Janis I'm also interested in knowing better way if someone can come with. Also I'll not be bothered as 20 doesn't sounds like a huge number for me. It is a one time job --right. If you have same rules for different  enums you can reuse them(if possible).

Comment: The approach I am now following comes from a colleague: I will use Enums and will assign 0x02 the logical value "identifyRangeStart" and 0xFF the value "identifyRangeEnd" (or similar). I hope anyone using the Enum will see that these are unusual values and will check the comment that furher explains it. Thanks for the help, your solution still is the cleanest :)

Answer (score 3):

Actually I would use the enum values as identifiers only and not as the actual values. Something like this:

```
class MessageType {
    public enum MessageTypeEnum {
        get, 
        set, 
        identify
    }

    public static MessageTypeEnum getLogicalValue (byte numericalValue)
    {
       if (numericalValue == 0x00) 
          return MessageTypeEnum.get; 
       else if (numericalValue == 0x01)
          return MessageTypeEnum.set;
       else
          return MessageTypeEnum.identify;
    }
}
```

And use it this way:

```
if (MessageType.getLogicalValue(messageBytes[x]) == MessageTypeEnum.identify) {
    // do stuff
}
```

You can of course use a `switch` instead of `if... else if...`, that depends on your personal preference and needs.

As stated in other answer, if you want to use a direct comparison, you'll need to create a custom class and implement the equality comparison to what you need.

Comment: Actually the "else if" statements are not required. if (numericalValue == 0x00) return MessageTypeEnum.get just there, it will return if the evaluation is true.

Comment: @hmartinezd yeah, I know, but IMO is more readable this way. Again, I think is just a matter of personal preferences.

Comment: I do agree with you, I just wanted to point out an alternative. It's always a matter of preferences.

Comment: I honestly do not see how your code has any advantage over my own suggestion. When using your class, the chance to "hit" the right value when wrongly directly using the enum is even lower than with my solution. Don't get me wrong here: I personally know that I cannot use the nested enum in both directions - which your code further implies. But when using the class and the nested enum, such a mistake can happen none the less (even with comments).

Comment: @Janis sorry, with your question I understood that you were looking for a way to use enums to solve your problem in a clean way, but now I see that what you want is a fool-proof direct comparison solution (or as fool-proof it could get), As Sriram Sakthivel's answer states, enums are not the way to go then.

Comment: No reason to be sorry, you tried to help and you did your part here. Someone else who would not know how to use my suggested semi-solution (or your adaption of it) might still benefit from it. So thanks for the answer :)
I would though still assign the values in the enum corresponding to the numerical values as far as possible. This increases the chance, that in case of using the enum the wrong way (as stated in my code) the code would still work.

Answer (score 0):

you could refactor the method signature and do the following and it will tell you which `enum` by name it actually is by passing in the value look at the method I just refactored for you and how to call it below

```
public static string getLogicalValue(byte numericalValue)
{
    Type type = numericalValue.GetType();
    var name = Enum.GetName(typeof(MessageTypeEnum), numericalValue);
    if (numericalValue < 0x02)
        return name;
    else
        return MessageTypeEnum.identify.ToString();
}
```

Call the static method like this

```
var enumValue = getLogicalValue(0x02);
```

the return string will be `identify`
 or if you wanted to do a switch/case statement you could do the following as well

```
    public static string getLogicalValue(byte numericalValue)
    {
        Type type = numericalValue.GetType();
        var name = Enum.GetName(typeof(MessageTypeEnum), numericalValue);
        switch(numericalValue)
        {
            case 0x00:
                {
                    name= (MessageTypeEnum.get.ToString());
                    break;
                }
            case 0x01:
                {
                    name= (MessageTypeEnum.set.ToString());
                    break;
                }

             default:   
                {
                    name= (MessageTypeEnum.identify.ToString());
                    break;
                }
        }
        return name;
    }
```

Comment: All you basicly do is cast the possibly wrong enum into a string. So your code still has the original problem: numerical values might lead to an invalid logical value (in your case a null-string). I therefor consider this a worse solution than my own. Thanks for the approach though. 
And btw: your "Type type = ..." is never used and can be deleted.

Comment: @chuex that's correct I did not write all of the scenario's however I will edit the answer and use default. thanks for pointing that out..